# how to make a apriori table with dynamicaly mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot

i have 3 tables like this

```
create table order_match
(
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
order_status_id int(10) not null
);

create table order_match_detail
(
 id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
 order_match_id int(10) not null,
 product_id int(10) NOT NULL
);

create table product
(
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
name varchar(255) not null
);

Insert into order_match (id, order_status_id)
select 1, 6 union all
select 2, 7 union all
select 3, 6 union all
select 4, 6;

Insert into order_match_detail (id, order_match_id, product_id)
select 1, 1, 147  union all
select 2, 2, 148 union all
select 3, 3, 147 union all
select 4, 4, 149 union all
select 5, 4, 147;

Insert into product (id, name)
select 147, 'orange' union all
select 148, 'carrot' union all
select 149, 'Apple';
```

with `order_match.id = order_match_detail.order_match_id`
and `order_match_detail.product_id = product.id`

i want to make the data where `order_status_id` not in 7 then it's success transaction and from that success transaction, if the transaction buy apple, then the column of apple contain `1` else if not buying, then `0` and this is my expected results, i want to make this data to analyze in

```
 id (in order_match)    |    Orange  |  Carrot  |   Apple
    
    1                           1            0           0
    3                           1            0           0
    4                           1            0           1
```

with that problem i can solve it with this query

```
select om.id,
  count(DISTINCT case when omd.product_id = 147 THEN 1 END) Orange,
  count(DISTINCT case when omd.product_id = 148 THEN 1 END) Carrot,
  count(DISTINCT case when omd.product_id = 149 THEN 1 END) Apple
  from order_match om
left join order_match_detail omd
  on om.id = omd.order_match_id
where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by om.id
```

the real problem is, in my real database, it's contain **1550 product_id**, how to make it automatically so no need to input manual the product_id untill 1550 product_id

this is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c0eb7fe1b012ab1c909d37e325a8d434

i've tried the new queries like this and it still wrong

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when product.name = ''',
      product.name,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(product.name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from product;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT omd.order_match_id, ', @sql, ' from order_match_detail omd
left join order_match om
  on omd.order_match_id = om.id
left join product p
  on omd.product_id = p.id
where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by omd.order_match_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Are you planning to have 1550 columns?

Comment: we can use  cursors in stored procedures

Comment: yes sir, it's not problem because i want to analyze it with another data mining software @tcadidot0

Comment: can you give me a suggestion about store procedure @SivaKoteswaraRao

Comment: All those product_id are running numbers from 1 to 1550? Also, what MySQL/MariaDB version are you using?

Comment: yes in my real data, it's 1 until 1550, im using mysql version 5.7

Comment: do u have to give distinct alias names to count(when prodid=149 then 1) (for each prodid comparision)

Comment: The _data mining software_ is developed in-house or a third-party software? If it's in-house developed, you may want to consider a doing it from the front-end?

Comment: the distinct for the cases when users buying more than 1 in product_id, so the disctinct are avoid to value other than 1 for every each product_id @SivaKoteswaraRao

Comment: nope sir. it's third party software called RapidMiner, the mysql i use to ollect the data and then make it CSV format and import to RapidMiner @tcadidot0

Comment: Would it help to have large boolean operations, including `BIT_COUNT`?  See MySQL 8.0, which can handle `BLOB`-sized bit strings.  (Previously the limit was 64-bit `BIGINT`.)

Comment: do you mean it cant solved with mysql 5.7?

Comment: No doubt it's been mentioned before, but handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: after long discussion and research, its because some of product name are have special character not fit in format mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is almost correct you were missing on alias instead of p you should use 'product' in second query, it would work

```
         SET group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
           'count(case when product.name = ''',
          product.name,
          ''' then 1 end) AS ',
          '"',replace(product.name, ' ', ''),'"'
        )
      )  INTO @sql
    from product;
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT omd.order_match_id as id, ', @sql, ' from order_match_detail omd
    left join order_match om
      on omd.order_match_id = om.id
    left join product product
      on omd.product_id = product.id
    where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
    group by omd.order_match_id');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

You can remove `DISTINCT` from  `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT` if you are sure that product id's is having unique names for each id's

Then i would get the [exact](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=93c52e7ebc03d68e420b0278937d0e56) result as you mentioned in question else just you will see, Apple column first and Orange column last, overall result is as [expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1059a7e4ba34a77f90b64820c5986a3a).

Comment: thankyou for your answer. unfortunately when i want to run PREPARE stmt FROM @sql it says Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order_match_detail omd left join order_match om   on omd.order_match_id = o' at line 1

Comment: I am attaching the db fiddle its giving expected output, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1059a7e4ba34a77f90b64820c5986a3a

Comment: yes that's the problem i've met sir, before this question are made, the fiddle are right but when it applied in my real database, it was always same like that notification, i assume this issue because some of product_name are not in right format, but i dont know

Comment: you were having error in syntax because the columns that you generate in first query alias was in mismatch with the second query from product table,  try copy pasting my solution exactly in your database, do you still see the error ? can you provide more sample data, i dont think you should get any syntax error here.

Comment: yes i've copy paste the solution you've made but the error are like that  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order_match_detail omd left join order_match om on omd.order_match_id = o' at line 1

Comment: which version of mysql are you using ? seeing your error -  I think you should remove the ',' in '@sql' query in second part "@sql, ' from order_match_detail"  --> try removing ',' and run it, if you prepare yourself the statement probably you are putting ',' before 'from' remove it, i ran in database but it works fine.

Comment: i used 5.7, can you add your suggested query on your answer so i can copy paste it if you dont mind

Comment: i've following your suggestion about remove the ',' but when i run set @sql its says Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@sql, ' from order_match om left join order_match_detail omd   on omd.order_matc' at line 1

Comment: check my solution i have added a new answer, in your product table, the product name can have special characters ?

Comment: I think you have special characters in data , you should use regexp_repalce to get off it, try running my solution in answer, edited to add it.

Comment: yes thats's my opinion, i think i have special characters on my database, anyway when i tried your new answers it says Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION brambang.REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist

Comment: You should specify this in original post, in MySQL 5.7 regexp is not present so you have to use nested replace function for each special char.

Comment: Can you use this in first query and check ?replace 'regexp_replace(....)' with 'replace(product.name, ',','')'

Comment: what do you mean in your last comment? can you edited in your answers please? thankyou very much

Comment: @FachryDzaky check i have added in answer

Comment: reedited Now you should be able to run for your data

Comment: im sorry sir, it says Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order_match_detail omd left join order_match om   on omd.order_match_id = o' at line 1

Comment: What kind of data you have in product name column can you add in your original post ?

Comment: do you mean add in all of the product name? it's less than 1600 data

Comment: only special case as a sample data also make sure if its confidential to alter accordingly

Comment: ok, i think this is product name which contain some special character 
1. Bayam 1 ikat (± 330g)
2. Telur Asin Yes (1 pak = 6 butir)
3. Alpukat Mentega Medium 2 buah (± 280g/bh)
4. PROMO: 2 X Telur Ayam Kampung (isi 6)

Comment: oh this is important.. let me recheck

Comment: still same sir :( Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'en from order_match_detail omd left join order_match om   on omd.order_match_id ' at line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217723/discussion-between-jfrd-and-fachry-dzaky).